# Facing problem when looping through over list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public class PriceDetail
{

    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Package { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string PackageType { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }

}

[WebMethod]
    public static string GetCardDetail(string category)
    {


        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        List<PriceDetail> pricingCard = new List<PriceDetail>();
        string query = "select [PricingID],[Package],[Currency],[Price],[PackageType] from [SeoDatabase].[dbo].[tbl_Pricing] where Category = @Category";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", category);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {

            PriceDetail priceDetail = new PriceDetail();

            priceDetail.ID = Convert.ToInt16(rdr["PricingID"]);

            priceDetail.Package = rdr["Package"].ToString();

            priceDetail.Currency = rdr["Currency"].ToString();

            priceDetail.Price = Convert.ToInt16(rdr["Price"]);

            priceDetail.PackageType = rdr["PackageType"].ToString();

            pricingCard.Add(priceDetail);

        }
        con.Close();

        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        string queryList = "select [Item] from [SeoDatabase].[dbo].[tbl_PricingItem] where PricingID = @pricingID";



        int i = 0;
        while(i < pricingCard.Count)
        {
            SqlCommand listCmd = new SqlCommand(queryList, con);

            con.Open();

            listCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pricingID", pricingCard[i].ID);

            SqlDataReader listReader = listCmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (listReader.Read())
            {
                items.Add(listReader["Item"].ToString());
            }

            pricingCard[i].Items = items;

            items.Clear();

            con.Close();

            i++;
        }



        string obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pricingCard);

        return obj;

    }
```

Every thing is going good when i reached on second loop while(i < pricingCard.Count) in this loop on 0 index its working properly and assigning right value to pricingCard[i].Items = items; problem is that when it goes for second index(1) it assigns the value correctly but also change the value of first index(0) and when loop moves for third time it changes the value of index(0).Items and index(1).Items with index(2).Items values
Please help me to solve

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not behaving as you might expect is that `items`, being of type `List<string>`, is a reference type, not a value type. This a concept that you will need to understand well whilst developing with managed languages such as C#. [MSDN - Reference and Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types)

Simplistically , what you are saying by `pricingCard[i].Items = items;` is that `pricingCard[i].Items` is now a reference to `items`. That means, at any given point after, an evaluation of `pricingCard[i].Items` will just "refer" you to `items`, therefore any changes to `items` will reflect on all reference you have made to it.

What you need to do, at the being of each loop, is to "re-instantiating" `items` with `items = new List<string>()`. This is to say: create a new instance of the list, and new instance to with the next iteration of `pricingCard[i].Items` will refer.

```
while(i < pricingCard.Count)
{
    items = new List<string>();
    // Do the rest of your process
}
```

Alternatively, add the items directly:

```
while (listReader.Read())
{
    pricingCard[i].Items.Add(listReader["Item"].ToString());
}
```

**P.S.**

Rather than using:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < pricingCard.Count)
{
    i++;
}
```

Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pricingCard.Count; i++)
{}
```

Comment: Thank you brother i put items = new List<string>(); now it assigning 0 count to index(0) and assign new values at index(1)

Comment: Can you be help me to solve this problem using any desk or skype